Flutter - [split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk!libflutter.so] JNI_OnLoad
I get this error in the GooglePlay console, since I published an update. I don't see this error in the firebase crashlytics dashboard, it only appears in the GooglePlay console.

There is not much information given in the stacktrace.


Only a small amount (0.35%) of my users are affected by this issue. The app runs fine on most devices.

I also used the Firebase Testlab and tested the production version on dozen of physical devices. Including devices that were shown in the GooglePlay console error. No issues were found.
Before I released the update I upgraded to the latest Flutter version. I think it has something to do with the Flutter (or gradle?) upgrade.
After researching a lot, I have no clue about how to solve this issue. I will soon reach the "bad behaviour threshold" => really annoying.
Can someone with more experience help & point me in the right direction on how to solve this or how to get more information on this error?
Update 6.6.2024:
I purchased a physical device that has the error (Xiaomi Redmi 9C). I couldn't reproduce the error. The App runs fine on the device i bought.
Update 10.6.2024
I could reproduce the error on the Redmi 9C device. Just had to try a little harder. What's interesting. This error only occurs in profile or release mode. No crash in debug mode!?
I couldn't reproduce this error on my other physical devices => Google Pixel 8 pro & Huawei Mate 20 pro.
I created a bug report on Github and sent the logs.
This issue is marked as P1 now (High-priority issues at the top of the work list).
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/149892
Let's see what happens.

Are you using TesnorFlow or MediaPipe in your app?

No, i don't use this

Hey @NaoKreuzeder did you check this official doc?
Check your android/app/build.gradle and add abiFilters accordingly

@ATV Thanks for the comment. I already set the abiFilters accordingly to the documentation. With previous releases there was never a problem.

Anyone got solution as I am also getting this error after using TensorFlow.
